# When to clear interval in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, intervals, clearinterval

I'm making a Food Drop game so black squares are falling down from the top of the screen and the player uses a platter to collect them. I'm doing this with an `array` so every time a new square is created program puts it on a certain position in array `food[]`.(all of this happen in `move()` function).

The problem is that after some time there are too many squares in array and it's too much to handle for the computer. I probably need to clear both intervals after some time, but I'm not really sure when. Any solution for this problem? The code also clears both intervals when the game reloads and it throws away old squares from `food[]` array.

There is a live example below.

```js
var main = function () {

    //Global variables
    var food = [];
    //Interval
    var interval;
 var interval2;

    //Radius size
    var size;

    var Xpos;

    var speed = 15;

    //Color
    var color;
 
 var score = 0;
 
 $('.btn').hover(function() {
  $('.btn').addClass('btn-hover');
 }, function() {
  $('.btn').removeClass('btn-hover');
 });
 $('.btn2').hover(function() {
  $('.btn2').addClass('btn-hover');
 }, function() {
  $('.btn2').removeClass('btn-hover');
 });

 $('.score').text("SCORE: " + score);
 
 var lives_left = 3;
    //Function that checks if two elements collide
    function collision($div1, $div2) {
        var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
        var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
        var h1 = $div1.outerHeight(true);
        var w1 = $div1.outerWidth(true);
        var b1 = y1 + h1;
        var r1 = x1 + w1;
        var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
        var y2 = $div2.offset().top;
        var h2 = $div2.outerHeight(true);
        var w2 = $div2.outerWidth(true);
        var b2 = y2 + h2;
        var r2 = x2 + w2;

        if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
        return true;
    }


    //Create a random circle
    var circleCreate = function () {

        if (interval) clearInterval(interval);

        food.push($('<div></div>'));
        var num = food.length - 1;
        size = 6;

        //1. Create a circle and append it to .container
        //2. Give it a random position
        //3. Color it
        //4. Give it a moving path

        food[num].appendTo('.food').addClass('circle').css('height', size + '%').css('width', size / 2 + '%');

        Xpos = Math.round(Math.random() * 95);
  if (Xpos <= 5) {
   Xpos += 5;    
  }
        food[num].css('left', Xpos + '%');

        //Choose the circle color
        var circleColor = function () {

            color = Math.random();

            if (color <= 0.1) {
                food[num].css('background-color', 'black'); //red    
            } else if (color <= 0.2) {
                food[num].css('background-color', 'black');   
            } else if (color <= 0.3) {
                food[num].css('background-color', 'black');   
            } else if (color <= 0.4) {
                food[num].css('background-color', 'black');    
            } else if (color <= 0.5) {
                food[num].css('background-color', 'black');    
            } else if (color <= 0.6) {
                food[num].css('background-color', 'black');    
            } else if (color <= 0.7) {
                food[num].css('background-color', 'black');    
            } else if (color <= 0.8) {
                food[num].css('background-color', 'black');    
            } else if (color <= 0.9) {
                food[num].css('background-color', 'black');   
            } else {
                food[num].css('background-color', 'black');    
            }
        }

 //Facts
 var fact = function() {

 var randomFact = Math.random();

 if (randomFact <= 0.05) {
  $('.fact').text("- Sladoled je porijeklom iz Kine");
 }
 else if(randomFact <= 0.1) { 
  $('.fact').text("- Sok od borovnice poboljsava memoriju.");
 }
 else if(randomFact <= 0.15) {
  $('.fact').text("- Hrani je potrebno sedam minuta da dode u zeludac iz usta."); 
 }
 else if(randomFact <= 0.2) {
  $('.fact').text("- Postoji oko 100.000 bakterija u jednoj litri pitke vode."); 
 }
 else if(randomFact <= 0.25) {
  $('.fact').text("- Lubenice mogu kostati do 70 eura u Japanu."); 
 }
 else if(randomFact <= 0.3) {
  $('.fact').text("- U sredstvima za ciscenje kuce i detrdgentima koji sadrze limun, ima vise limunovog soka od kupovne limunade."); 
 }
 else if(randomFact <= 0.35) {
  $('.fact').text("- U salici kave ima preko 1000 kemikalija."); 
 }
 else if(randomFact <= 0.4) {
  $('.fact').text("- Prosjecni Francuz pojede oko 500 puzeva godisnje."); 
 }
 else if(randomFact <= 0.45) {
  $('.fact').text("- Nakon sto se Popaj pojavio u Americi, prodaja spinata se podigla 33%.");
 }
 else if(randomFact <= 0.5) {
  $('.fact').text("-  Pravi biseri se tope u octu.");
 }
 else if(randomFact <= 0.55) {
  $('.fact').text("- U drevnoj Kini, ljudi su cinili samoubojstvo tako sto bi pojeli pola kile soli.");
 }
 else if(randomFact <= 0.6) {
  $('.fact').text("- Banane sadrze kemikaliju koja cini ljude sretnim.");
 }
 else if(randomFact <= 0.65) {
  $('.fact').text("- Jabuke pripadaju porodici ruza.");
 }
 else if(randomFact <= 0.7) {
  $('.fact').text("- Jabuke su ucinkovitije od kofeina pri jutarnjem razbudivanju. ");
 }
 else if(randomFact <= 0.75) { 
  $('.fact').text("- Kozje mlijeko koristi se cesce od kravljeg.");
 }
 else if(randomFact <= 0.8) {
  $('.fact').text("- Prvi proizvod oznacen bar-kodom bio je Wrigleyev paketic guma za zvakanje.");
 }
 else if(randomFact <= 0.85) {
  $('.fact').text("- Sendvic je dobio ime prema Johnu Montaguu, 4. Grofu od Sandwicha (18.st), covjeku koji ga je volio jesti tijekom kartanja. ");
 }
 else if(randomFact <= 0.9) {
  $('.fact').text("- Kinezi godisnje iskoriste oko 45 milijardi stapica za jelo.");
 }
 else if(randomFact <= 0.95) {
  $('.fact').text("- Kina je najveci proizvodac cesnjaka na svijetu, s otprilike 77% ukupne svjetske proizvodnje. ");
 }
 else if(randomFact <= 1) {
  $('.fact').text("- Jagode imaju vise vitamina C od narance.");
 }

 }
  fact();
        //Wall colliders
        //Collision function
        //Function that checks if two elements collide

        var move = function () {
            interval = setInterval(function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < food.length; ++i) {
                    var posTop = food[i].offset().top / $(window).height() * 100;
                    if (posTop < 100)  { 
      posTop += 1;
      if(collision($('.player'),food[i])) {
       score++;
       food[i].remove();
       $('.score').text("SCORE: " + score);
       break;
      }
      else if(collision($('.dead_line'),food[i])) {
       food[i].remove();
       lives_left--;
       $('.lives').children().last().remove();
       if(lives_left === 0) {
       $('.bodovi').text("Score: " + score);
        num = 0;
        i = 0;
        score = 0;
        food = [];
        lives_left = 3;
        clearInterval(interval);
        clearInterval(interval2);
        $('.food').children().remove();
        $('.container').hide();
        $('.end').show();
        break;
       }
       break;
      }
     }
                    food[i].css('top', posTop + '%');
                }
            }, speed);
        }

        //Color the circle
        circleColor();

        move();
    }
 
$('.btn').click(function() {

$('.score').text("SCORE: " + score);
$('<div>').appendTo('.lives').attr('id', 'life').addClass('prvi');
$('<div>').appendTo('.lives').attr('id', 'life').addClass('drugi');
$('<div>').appendTo('.lives').attr('id', 'life').addClass('treci');
$('.btn').hide();
$('.container').show();

 interval2 = setInterval(function() {
  $('.score').text("SCORE: " + score);
  circleCreate();
 }, 400);
});

$('.btn2').click(function() {
$('.end').hide();
$('.score').text("SCORE: " + score);
$('<div>').appendTo('.lives').attr('id', 'life').addClass('prvi');
$('<div>').appendTo('.lives').attr('id', 'life').addClass('drugi');
$('<div>').appendTo('.lives').attr('id', 'life').addClass('treci');
$('.btn').hide();
$('.container').show();

 interval2 = setInterval(function() {
  $('.score').text("SCORE: " + score);
  circleCreate();
 }, 400);
});

    //Player moves with the mouse    
    $('.container').mousemove(function (e) {

        $('.player').css('left', e.pageX + 15 + 'px');

    });

}

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Trebuchet MS; 
}
.bg {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0%;
 left: 0%;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #EBEBEB;
}
.container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%; 
    left: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 82%;
    background-color: transparent;
 display: none;
}

.player {
    top: 92%;
    position: inherit;
    height: 5%;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 4;
}

.btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 45%;
    height: 10%;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #1D1D1D;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height: 40px;
 z-index: 4;
}
.circle {
 position: absolute;
 top: 5%;
 height: 10%;
  width: 5%;
 z-index: 3;
 background-size: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.score {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 5%;
    height: 10%;
    width: 20%;
    font-size: 25px;
 font-family:     
}

.score_line {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 0.1%;
    width: 100%;
}
.dead_line {
    position: absolute;
    top: 99%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 1%;
    width: 100%;     
}
#life {
    position: absolute;
    height: 8%;
    width: 8%;
 top: 5%;
 background-color: red;
}
.prvi {
 left: 5%;
}
.drugi {
 left: 15%;
}
.treci {
 left: 25%;
}

.start {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0%;
 left: 0%;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: transparent;
}


.game_over {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 30%;
    height: 15%;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 3;
  font-family: "Lucida Console",Monaco, monospace;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.bodovi {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 38%;
    height: 15%;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 3;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black;
}
.end {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0%;
 left: 0%;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: transparent;
 display: none;
}
.fact {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 5%;
    height: 15%;
    width: 95%;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 3;
 font-family: Trebuchet MS;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
 text-align: center;
}
.btn2 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    top: 60%;
    left: 45%;
    height:10%;
    width:10%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #1D1D1D;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.btn-hover {
 background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<div class="start">
 <div class="btn">PLAY</div>
</div>
 <div class="bg"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="player"></div>
        <div class="food"></div>
        <div class="lives"></div>
        
        <div class="score"></div>
        <div class="dead_line"></div>
    </div>

<!--Kraj igre-->
<div class="end">
 <div class="game_over">GAME OVER</div>
 <div class="bodovi"></div>
 <!--Igraj ponovo-->
 <div class="btn2">PLAY</div>
 <div class="fact"></div>
</div>
    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  
</body>
```

Comment: There's a lot of code to go through there but if I understand you rightly removing the elements from the food array and clearing it's interval when it reaches the bottom of the screen should work.
The .shift array method will allow you to remove the first element of an array which may be useful (assuming they all have the same speed so first in, first out).

Comment: Please put a mouse cursor back, you cannot see when you move out of the screen.

Comment: On a side note, you are setting an interval variable. But that's a global, so it only references one timer. You need to create an array with timers that can be cross referenced with the falling blocks array.